# SQL join 2 rows into 1 with conditions

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a table with updated and inserted values. So, most IDs have 2 rows, one for insert, other for update (there is an "operator" column which has value UPDATED or value INSERTED). Sample data:

```
operator | ID | row2 | row3
===========================
updated  | 01 |      | 231
===========================
inserted | 01 | abc  | 123
===========================
updated  | 02 | khj  | 567
===========================
inserted | 02 | klo  | 567
===========================
inserted | 03 | nmb  | 900
```

My task is to join these 2 rows in 1 grouping them by their ID. But, all values have to be from the "update" row AND if there are some NULL values in the "update", they must be taken from the "insert" row.

Desired results:

```
 ID  | row2 | row3
==================
 01  | abc  | 231
==================
 02  | khj  | 567
==================
 03  | nmb  | 900
==================
```

The goal is to have all distinct IDs with the newest data.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

I have tried implementing the following logic, but it doesn't return me the newest data:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(Field1) AS Field1,
    MAX(Field2) AS Field2
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    ID;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this -

```
Select 
u.ID, 
NVL(u.row2, i.row2), 
NVL(u.row3, i.row3) -- and so on for more columns
from
(Select * from tableName where operator = 'updated') u,
(Select * from tableName where operator = 'inserted') i
where u.ID = i.ID;
```

If your table has data such that there isn't any record with 'updated', you would need LEFT OUTER JOIN, so you may use below query then -

```
Select 
i.ID, 
NVL(u.row2, i.row2), 
NVL(u.row3, i.row3) -- and so on for more columns
from
(Select * from tableName where operator = 'updated') u,
(Select * from tableName where operator = 'inserted') i
where u.ID(+) = i.ID;
```

Comment: but I replaced it with CASE and it works!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to select rows, with `update` first and then the `insert` if there is no update.  So one method is:

```
select t.*
from table_name  t
where t.operator = 'UPDATED' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from table_name t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.operator = 'UPDATED'
                 );
```

Comment: I have to do this on column level, not only row as a whole

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```
   SELECT
      a.*
    FROM
      table_name a
    WHERE a.operator = 'UPDATED'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      b.*
    FROM
      table_name b
    WHERE b.operator = 'INSERTED'
      AND b.ID NOT IN
      (SELECT
        c.ID
      FROM
        table_name c
      WHERE c.operator = 'UPDATED'
        AND c.ID = b.ID)
```

Note: If you want or need to remove duplicates, you can replace: UNION ALL with UNION,

graciously.

Comment: this gives me only values from updated rows